# Can I transfer Minecraft from a computer to iOS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has been playing Minecraft on our home computer for a couple of years now.  He just got an iPad Mini 2 for his birthday. Is it possible to transfer his game and his saves onto his iPad Mini 2?

Answer (score 20):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Minecraft for the PC and Minecraft: Pocket Edition (for tablets and phones) are two seperate games. In order to enable your son to play on the iPad, you will need to purchase Minecraft PE from the app store, and he will not be able to play in the same world he has on the PC.

Comment: Another thing of note here is that the Portable Edition is not necessarily the same set of features as the desktop version; it's very likely that there are huge, noticeable discrepancies between the two versions.

Comment: You might be able to find a world converter or editor, but yes there are differences between what exists in the two games and how they work, and their data codes, and there are differences between versions of each, so any editor/translator would need to be pretty detailed or else there could be weird side-effects.

Comment: This information is false @shanodin

Comment: Who is upvoting this answer? @shanodin is making stuff up. Of course you have to purchase the game again, but maps *can* be transferred.

Answer (score 16):

You can port maps from the PC with very little differences...

Blocks that exist in the PC version will NOT be transferred over (such as command blocks).

Here is a very good tutorial on how to port maps:

**Please note that you will have to buy the FULL version of Minecraft Pocket Edition. You can use iFUNBOX to browse the file system of the iDevice.**

**Your device does not have to be jailbroken.**

Comment: Thanks for providing a real answer, but the link seems to be broken.

Comment: What link is broken? Does the video not load?

Comment: Yeah the video does not load for me, but that seems to be a SE problem. The [direct link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XEXAjev5Fk) works.

Comment: The video loads for me just fine...

Comment: The video is now permanently removed. (Which explains why we ask users to actually _answer_ in their answers, instead of linking to information that is not stored on this website...)