# Can I make my world a seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I look my world has a seed, although I didn't start it with a seed.

When I give my son that seed he can't see my buildings.

How can I let him load up my world on his iPad?

Comment: Are you playing on PC?

Comment: The seed is for generating the world, if you want to share an edited world (e.g. one with your creations in) you need to share the save file. (I'm not sure this is easily possible on mobile devices)

Comment: As DBS says, seeds are just for generating the terrain; the relatively short number couldn't store information about all the ways you've edited the world (and it's not a password to edit the world on a server or anything either). If you don't choose a seed, one is chosen at (pseudo)random. If you want to share a world with the buildings in it, seeds aren't the way to go. You'll need to share the save file, the process for which will differ depending on what you're playing the game on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I upload a seed, will my creations be saved on it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219482/if-i-upload-a-seed-will-my-creations-be-saved-on-it)

Comment: I don't really think it's a duplicate because this question seems to more stress how to give his son the worlds, and not whether or not "uploading the seed" (whatever that means, I assume also just sharing it) will also give the creations.

Answer (score 8):

'Seed' is a programming term. In Minecraft, the 'Seed' is the starting number that is fed into the algorithm that's used in generating the world.  If you do not enter a seed when creating a new world, Minecraft will generate a random number to use as the seed. However, if you enter the seed of your world when creating another new world, that seed is then fed into the algorithm and then the terrain, villages, dungeons, ores, etc are all going to be exactly the same as **WHEN YOUR WORLD WAS CREATED**.

In other words, what you do to the world AFTER its first created (your buildings etc) has nothing to do with the seed.

Also, not all platforms that Minecraft is on can share seeds, nor will they generate the same worlds. Seeds for the PC version won't generate the same world on a Xbox due to the console versions being a very old version of Minecraft compared to the PC. I don't know about iOS but I doubt it would generate the same world either. Seeds **can** be shared between PS3 and Xbox 360 and between PS4 and Xbox One. The PE version of Minecraft has an entirely different algorithm compared to PC or consoles from what I understand.

If your goal is to let him have your world as it is after you have modified it by playing the game, well that depends on what version of Minecraft you created it in and what version you are playing it in as to whether its even possible.  I think @Faquarl covered that aspect well.

Comment: The algorithm used by the RNG (random number generator) can and most likely will be different on some if not all platforms. Unless Mojang wrote there own RNG that they can implement on the varying platforms.

Answer (score 2):

As it is said in the comments, the seed is just the starting point. The same seed only means what your son has the same world as you when you started. You can see more about it here:

- [Seed - Level Generation - GamePedia.com](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation))

So the thing you want is importing your save to his iPad.
And it is a problem if you don't have the same game version. You can see about PC-iOS for example here:

- [Can I-transfer-Minecraft-from-a-computer-to-iOS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203412/can-i-transfer-minecraft-from-a-computer-to-ios)

But it seems to be possible between PC/MAC and XBOX (both ways).

- [Export XBOX 360 to MAC or PC](http://marc.tv/blog/export-xbox-360-minecraft-maps-to-mac-or-pc/)

It is also possible between pocket versions (iPad, Android & cie).

- [How to transfer minecraft pocket edition world between iPads](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148549/how-to-transfer-minecraft-pocket-edition-world-between-ipads)