# How to transfer Minecraft from Pocket Edition to PC Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have paid for and downloaded Minecraft on my phone and want to download it on my PC (the version run by Microsoft) without paying again. It would be great if you could help.

Comment: @pppery That question has been closed as a duplicate already, I will instead vote to close this question as a duplicate of [Can I transfer Minecraft from a computer to iOS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203412/can-i-transfer-minecraft-from-a-computer-to-ios). Edit: actually that's a different question, it asks about PC to PE, while this one asks PE to PC. I will simply vote to leave this open instead, because the other question is closed now. Edit 2: This question is not even the same as the suggested duplicate, this is about the game, the other about game files (maps).

Comment: Yeah, looks like I messed up here, and am convinced by Edit 2. Retracting duplicate flag.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Minecraft: Pocket Edition is for devices only, and PC or Windows 10 Editions are completely separate from MCPE. You will have to buy the PC version or not play it at all.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Pocket Edition (which is avaliable on phones) and Java Edition (which is mainly used on PC) are different games with different features, which are not compatible.

You will have to buy each version (PC, Console, PE) separately.

There is a *Windows 10 Edition* which is basically PE edition ported on PC, and it is free for Java version owners. But not for other version owners.

Comment: Could he potentially run the APK from his phone with an emulator? Assuming that a) it's legal and b) he's been playing on an Android phone? Not an ideal way to play, obviously, but just a thought.

Comment: @pushasha technically it might be possible, but perfomance is not going to be good. Also actually playing the game will be extra painful due to controls.

Comment: @pushasha, it's possible and, on my machine, it's playable, although slower, as Revolver_Ocelot mentioned. But, as the OP mentioned he wanted the Microsoft version on his PC, the only answer really is no, it's not possible.

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato The fact that he wanted the PC version wasn't entirely clear until the edit that was made more recently. Given that, I agree.